# Count post in laravel default dashboard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I've used auth scaffold to create login and auth system for my site. I want to count the post and show it in the dashboard. But in `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php` there is just one line code `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to return view. How do i count post and show it in the dashboard.

Comment: Create a `DashboardController` (for ex) and a route to `dashboard` and do anything that you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out.

I found that when we use laravel auth scaffolding laravel uses `use AuthenticatesUsers;` in `LoginController.php` and `use RegistersUsers;` in `RegisterController.php` which is known as trait. And both trait use another trait `RedeirectUsers.php`  to redirect or show view after we login or register a new user. It would not be a nice idea messing up those files.But instead I used balde injection method in `dashboard.blade.php`

```
@inject('posts','App\Post') //place it in top of dashboard.blade.php
{{$posts->count()}}
```

No need to make extra view,models & controller to pass data to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count posts which are belong to the user, you can use [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates) method:

```
$postsCount = Post::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->count;
```

Or using [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships):

```
$postsCount = auth()->user()->posts()->count();
```

Comment: And how do I pass it to view ? There is only `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to return view.

Comment: You have to create method, route and view for the dashboard and use this code in a controller. `$redirectTo` is just a property which contains URL to redirect to after user login.

Comment: I used  auth scaffold for that.

Comment: @ZacharyDale auth scaffold does only include auth related functionality. You'll still need to create dashboard routes, controller and views.

Comment: @alexet I didn't quite get you. I have controllers `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php` , view `dashboard.blade.php` and route `Auth::routes();`

Comment: @ZacharyDale I'd recommend you to start with reading or watching some tutorial where you'll learn about how controllers and routes work in Laravel.

Comment: please go through my answer.